# What happened with materials in eevee when linking?

Tags: shaders, eevee-render-engine, transparency, linked-data

I have this problem with the material in the eyes of characters linked to a scene. The scene that contains the linked characters shows this way when rendered with Cycles:
[image]

When I change to eevee it is ok in viewport, but the materials disappear on the eyes: (on linked file)
[image]

I can't modify the materials when the characters are linked. So in the blend file of the character I set the material to use alpha. With eevee, it shows ok in viewport but not in render:
[image]

Cycles works good in this second case too.

Please someone help me with this issue!!

Comment: Please insert images into your Question via edit. External links are not allowed, they are not permanent and broken links brakes meaningful of your Questions. Keep in mind your Question is not just to be solved for you, but also knowledge base for others. Thank you keeping site useful.

Comment: Does issue appears also in original blend with Eevee or just when linked? Under material check Alpha blend mode type  https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/150785/2214

Comment: It is wierd it appears differently in both files... I'll put the images to the question

Comment: From your last comment, I don't think we can understand more. If you still have an issue please attach blend with eye. Thank you https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com